# Retagging of [heart-gold] and [soul-silver]

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been looking through various questions, and I feel `[heart-gold]` and `[soul-silver]` should be retagged as `[heartgold]` and `[soulsilver]` respectively, as in the official titles the name is one single word. What does everybody else think?

***Looks like we're going to stick with the hyphenated tags.***

Answer (score 3):

They are two camel cased words each.  HeartGold and SoulSilver. Given that we use lowercase tags here, replacing the camel casing with a dash is the logical option in my opinion.

Comment: I was thinking this, however tags like `[youtube]` is one word on Super User (and WebApps.SE). Would this be because people think of YouTube as "Youtube"?

Comment: Nobody has ever felt inclined to type YouTube as you-tube. It practically is it's own word now. People who use decent spelling/grammar and know how tagging works on these sites nearly all used heart-gold and soul-silver.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that makes sense. I guess I'll retag my question as `[fire-red]` and `[leaf-green]` if we're going to stick with hyphenated camel cased words.